# Is it possible to ORDER BY a computed column without including it in the result set?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this query:

```
SELECT Column1, Column2, Column3, /* computed column */ AS SortColumn
FROM Table1
ORDER BY SortColumn
```

`SortColumn` serves no other purpose as to define an order for sorting the result set. Thus I'd like to omit it in the result set to decrease the size of the data sent to the client. The following fails …

```
SELECT Column1, Column2, Column3
FROM (
    SELECT Column1, Column2, Column3, /* computed column */ AS SortColumn
    FROM Table1
    ORDER BY SortColumn
) AS SortedTable1
```

… because of:

> Msg 1033, Level 15, State 1
>
> The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP or FOR XML is also specified.

So there's this hacky solution:

```
SELECT Column1, Column2, Column3
FROM (
    SELECT TOP /* very high number */ Column1, Column2, Column3, /* computed column */ AS SortColumn
    FROM Table1
    ORDER BY SortColumn
) AS SortedTable1
```

Is there a clean solution I'm not aware of, since this doesn't sound like a rare scenario?

---

**Edit:**
The solutions already given work indeed fine for the query I referred to. Unfortunately, I left out an important detail: The (already existent) query consists of two `SELECT`s with a `UNION` in between, which changes the matter pretty much (again simplified, and hopefully not too simplified):

```
SELECT Column1, Column2, Column3
FROM Table1
UNION ALL
SELECT Column1, Column2, Column3
FROM Table1
ORDER BY /* computed column */
```

> Msg 104, Level 16, State 1
>
> ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if the statement contains a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator.

So this error message clearly says that I have to put the computed column in both of the select lists. So there we are again with the subquery solution which doesn't reliably work, as pointed out in the answers.

Comment: Can't you move the computation to the ORDER BY?

Comment: What is it you're actually trying to do? This might be an XY problem - why do you need a subquery that's *ordered*? Why do you need a subquery at all? Why don't you just put the computed column in the `order by` clause?

Comment: @Luaan Because I didn't know I could compute the order in place.  Trying it …

Comment: Dont know why this question get so big when gordon and daniel already give the right answer.

Comment: @Luaan I've made an update to my post which invalidates putting the computed column in the `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I've made an update to my post which invalidates putting the computed column in the `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: Yup, in that case, just use my answer :) The fact that you have to select the column in a subquery has no bearing on what you return to the client - just don't select it in the outer query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If, for whatever reason, it's not practical to do the calculation in the `ORDER BY`, you can do something quite similar to your attempt:

```
SELECT Column1, Column2, Column3
FROM (
    SELECT Column1, Column2, Column3, /* computed column */ AS SortColumn
    FROM Table1
) AS SortedTable1
ORDER BY SortColumn
```

Note that all that's changed here is that the `ORDER BY` is applied to the outer query. It's perfectly valid to reference columns in the `ORDER BY` that don't appear in the `SELECT` clause.

Comment: As far as I can tell, this even works after my edit (two `SELECT`s with `UNION` instead of simple `SELECT`).

Comment: @xehpuk - yes, this answer still works. My psychic powers are strong today

Answer (score 6):

You don't need to have a computed column in the select statement to use it in an order by

```
SELECT Column1, Column2, Column3
FROM Table1
ORDER BY /* computed column */
```

If you need to do it using UNION, then do the UNION in a cte, and the order by in the select, making sure to include all the columns you need to do the calculation in the CTE

```
WITH src AS (
    SELECT Column1, Column2, Column3, /* computation */ ColumnNeededForOrderBy
    FROM Table1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT Column1, Column2, Column3, /* computation */ ColumnNeededForOrderBy
    FROM Table2
)
SELECT Column1, Column2, Column3
FROM src
ORDER BY ColumnNeededForOrderBy
```

If you don't care to be specific with the column name, you can use the column index and skip the CTE.  I don't like this because you might add a column to the query later and forget to update the index in the ORDER BY clause (I've done it before).  Also, the query plans will likely be the same, so it's not like the CTE will cost you anything.

```
SELECT Column1, Column2, Column3, /* computation */ 
FROM Table1
UNION ALL
SELECT Column1, Column2, Column3, /* computation */ 
FROM Table2
ORDER BY 4
```

Answer (score 1):

Just put the expression in the `order by`:

```
SELECT Column1, Column2, Column3, 
FROM Table1
ORDER BY <computed column>
```

Comment: I left out important information so this doesn't work any more. See my edit.

Answer (score 1):

The reason this is forbidden is that the ordering of the outer select has nothing to do with the ordering of the inner select - not by contract. So if you use `order by` without a `top` clause, you're obviously making a mistake. By using `top` the way you do, you simply hide the error, but you still have the same mistake.

Your hack only works because the engine happened to preserve the order - but that's not a given, and there's no way to enforce that (other than using `order by` in the outer query). For example, a different index usage or parallel execution can scramble your data.

So no, there isn't another way - you need to `order by` in the outer query, and that requires you to output the column you want to sort by in the subquery. And unless you're using `*`, it's not like it makes any difference - you don't need to select it in the *outer* select, just the inner one. And only the outer select is sent to the client :)

Answer (score 1):

The only place for an `ORDER BY` is the outer most statement.

Of course there are exceptions: If you for example need the `TOP` record for a filtered list (e.g. the last valid value on a given date). But in these cases you **must** combine `ORDER BY` with `TOP`.

Only the outer most `ORDER BY` will sort the list you get.

Answer (score 1):

After the edit looks like this is what you need

```
SELECT Column1, Column2, Column3
FROM
    ( 
    SELECT Column1, Column2, Column3
    FROM Table1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Column1, Column2, Column3
    FROM Table1
    )
ORDER BY /* computed column */
```